# Why does not my react component re-render on redux store state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm stating to learn react and redux and I cannot figure out why my react component does not re-render after redux store state change.

Here is my code:

```
const initialState = { value: 'Loading...' }

function onSetName(state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type === 'doc/docnamechanged') {
    return {
      ...state,
      value: action.payload
    }
  }
  return state
}

export const setName = text => {
  return {
    type: 'doc/docnamechanged',
    payload: text
  }
}

export const store = configureStore({ reducer: onSetName })
store.subscribe(() => Layout(), App());

export default function App() {  
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<Layout />}>
        <Route path="/1" element={<PublicPage />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

thats my dispatch

```
  if (store.getState().value != "AD") {
    store.dispatch(setName("AD"));
  }
```

```
function Layout() {
  console.log(store.getState().value);

  const name = store.getState().value;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="header">
        <img className="logo" src="images/logotype.png" alt="logo" />
        <div className="UpperTitle">
          {name}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

So I can see in console that `store.getState().value` does change, but in rendered `<div className="UpperTitle">` `{name}` does not change. As you can see I tried to subscribe my App() function as well, but that did not help at all. Appreciate any help.

I manage to make it somehow work if I subscibe render() in index.js, but that seemed wrong and cause a warning message

```
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; triggering nested component updates from render is not allowed. If necessary, trigger nested updates in componentDidUpdate.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `store.getState` in a component doesn't subscribe it to any changes, it simply gets the state once and that's it. Something else would need to occur to trigger the `Layout` component to rerender so `store.getState` would be called again.

This isn't how we subscribe to the store in React components though. You can use the [`connect`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) Higher Order Component, or the more modern [`useSelector`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) hook.

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

function Layout() {
  const name = useSelector(state => state.value); // <-- subscribe to changes
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ name });
  }, [name]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="header">
        <img className="logo" src="images/logotype.png" alt="logo" />
        <div className="UpperTitle">
          {name}
        </div>
      </div>
      <Outlet /> // <-- for the nested routes 
    </div>
  );
}
```

You will need to ensure the Redux store is being provided to the React app.

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  value: 'Loading...'
};

function onSetName(state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type === 'doc/docnamechanged') {
    return {
      ...state,
      value: action.payload
    };
  }
  return state;
}

export const setName = text => ({
  type: 'doc/docnamechanged',
  payload: text,
});

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: onSetName,
});

export default function App() {  
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<Layout />}>
          <Route path="/1" element={<PublicPage />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Since it appears you are *actually* already using Redux-Toolkit, you should really use the current Redux patterns.

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { configureStore, createslice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  value: 'Loading...'
};

const nameSlice = createSlice({
  name: "name",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setName: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const {
  ...nameSlice.actions,
};

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: nameSlice.reducer,
});
```

```
import { setName } from '../path/to/name.slice';

...

dispatch(setName("AD"));
```

Comment: Thank you for such elaborate answer. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

for rerender an component you need call a hook or change a state inside it!

also `Layout` is not a `pure function`, and you can't call it in `subscibe`,

so remove this line from your code :

```
//store.subscribe(() => Layout(), App());
```

for rerender on store's state change you need to change component's state in `subscibe`:

first we create a state like below in `Layout` Component :

```
const [name, setNameState] = useState(store.getState().value);
```

then I add a `useEffect` hook to `Layout` and use `subscribe` method inside it :

```
useEffect(() => {
    store.subscribe(() => {
      console.log(store.getState().value);
      setNameState(store.getState().value);
    });
  }, []);
```

When the `redux state` value changes, the `subscribe` will called, after that the name state changes in `Layout` and component will be rerender.

[you can see demo of my answer](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-khayyam-zd37zl?file=/src/App.js:872-1022)